# Bash Script | if then for do

Tags: bash, latex

I'm trying to write a script that generates a LaTeX file. The first part of the script should display all the contents of the map in a tree form. The 2nd part should display the content of each executable file. The 1st part works, the 2nd doesn't. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\documentclass{article}" > script.tex
echo "\usepackage{listings}" >> script.tex
echo "\begin{document}" >> script.tex
echo "\begin{lstlisting}" >> script.tex
tree $1 >> script.tex
echo "\end{lstlisting}" >> script.tex

for file in $1
do
if [ -x $file ]
then
echo "\begin{lstlisting}" >> script.tex
cat $file >> script.tex
echo "\end{lstlisting}" >> script.tex
fi
done
echo "\end{document}" >> script.tex
```

Comment: please consider editing your question to include *why* you think the 2nd half isn't working. As is, we don't have your input file, so we are left to guess. I can comment that `[ -x $file ]` is asking 'Is $file have the executable bit set?' Is that what you really want? you're not executing below in the `cat $file`. Try using `[ -f $file ]` if you just want to be sure the input is a file. Good luck.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `for file in $1/*`, in place of `for file in $1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you call this script with a single directory argument, which gets passed in `$1`, and then probably you want to generate a `tex` file from the files in that dir. Here's the fix, with some other minor improvements and safeguards:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=script.tex
cat << EOF >$out
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
EOF
tree "$1" >> $out
echo "\end{lstlisting}" >> $out

for file in "$1"/*
do
    if [ -x "$file" ]
    then
        echo "\begin{lstlisting}" >> $out
        cat "$file" >> $out
        echo "\end{lstlisting}" >> $out
    fi
done
echo "\end{document}" >> $out
```

**UPDATE**

The `cat << EOF` is called a *Here Document*, you can read more about it in `man bash`. This is similar to a verbatim block in TeX, it's very useful to work with large blocks of texts rather than echoing things line by line. The text starts from `<< EOF` and ends before a line that starts with `EOF`. Instead of `EOF` you could use any other label, for example:

```
cat << HELLO
...
...
HELLO
```

A Here Document can be used as the standard input for a command. Here we use it as the standard input of `cat`, to echo it back. In my answer I redirected it to a file.

Comment: Could you explain me how does "cat << EOF > $out" work?